# How to access outer function variable inside nested function

Tags: typescript, closures

I am fairly new to JS and I am trying to understand closures:
I have a function like

```js
function generateColorsForKeys(allKeys: string | string[], userColors: ColorType = {}): { colors: ColorType; uniqueKeys: string[] } {
  const uniqueKeys = uniq(concat([], allKeys));
  const that = this;
  // I am using lodash reduce here
  // I need to get access to allKeys here
  const { colors }: { colors: ColorType } = reduce((acc, value: string) => {
    acc.colors[value] = userColors[value];
    if (!acc.colors[value]) {
     // access allKeys Here
    }
    return acc;
  }, {
    colors: {},
    i: 0,
  }, uniq(concat([], allKeys)));
  console.log('colors :>> ', colors);
  return {
    colors,
    uniqueKeys,
  };
}
```

Here I need to access the variable allKeys i.e the argument for outer function `generateColorsForKeys` inside the reduce function. My understanding of closures is that the outer variabls should be accessible but for some reason it is not accessible.

PS: **I am using strict mode**

Comment: Change `this.allKeys` to `allKeys`

Comment: it is the same thing only I don't have access to allKeys @Yousaf

Comment: btw this is typescript and not javascript... not a big difference but good to know ;)

Comment: It is accessible. You can just use `allKeys` at the point where you have your comment. If it's not working then create a runnable snippet which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: that was a wrong tag I agree, but it is just a superset only. Probably if I could get some hep here @dominik

Comment: Didn't @Yousaf already answer this? I don't understand what you're asking sorry. `allKeys` would be accessible to you within the reduce arrow function.

Comment: it is not accessible @dominik

Comment: It *is* accessible as you've written this snippet. If it's not in your code then create for us a runnable snippet which recreates the problem.

Comment: If my previous comment didn't solve the problem then please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)